# Migrated a drupal database from a preview site to a live site and am now getting an error

Tags: 6, migrations

Migrated a drupal database from a preview site to a live site and am now getting an error.

(I only moved the database)

`The selected file /tmp/filethQvCf could not be uploaded, because the destination css/css_4b1c49411f8ee294df61cf73ebc413c6.css is not properly configured.`

I should note that /sites/default/files/ctools/css is chmod 777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. As admin:

admin > settings > file system

The Temporary directory was set to a different path that didn't exist in the preview site.